# What's wrong with my manifest.json

Tags: php, json, service-worker

I'm trying to add a manifest.json to my web app (made in php) so the users can add it to their homescreen.

Here's my manifest json:

```
{
  "name": "OrganizaMeuCasamento",
  "short_name": "MeuCasamento",
  "theme_color": "#995a6d",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "https://meucasamento.organizaeventos.net",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logopwa.png",
      "sizes": "70x70",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
    {
    "src": "icon-256x256.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I linked it on my index.php but on my GoogleDevTools it doesn't get recognized.
What have I done wrong? It's a error on manifest.json itself or on the link on index.php

here is the link:
meucasamento.organizaeventos.net

image of GoogleDevTools
[image: googledevtools-no-manifest-detected]

Comment: You're missing a comma between your array items in `icons`.

Comment: If your editor doesn't validate JSON on-the-fly you can always use an online service like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: It doesn't help either to put stuff before `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "name": "OrganizaMeuCasamento",
  "short_name": "MeuCasamento",
  "theme_color": "#995a6d",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "https://meucasamento.organizaeventos.net",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logopwa.png",
      "sizes": "70x70",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
    "src": "icon-256x256.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

you forgot one `,` inside your icon array.
Now it should work if you use the good tag inside your html

Comment: mein gott! hahha... IT'S ALWAYS A COMMA! 
Well... thanks man!!! :D
regards!


info: on my index.php I wrote: 
`?>
<link rel="manifest" href"https://meucasamento.organizaeventos.net/manifest.json">
<?php`

Comment: you forgot a `=` in your html file too haha
`<link rel="manifest" href="https://meucasamento.organizaeventos.net/manifest.json">`

Comment: well... it's not always a comma... hahaha. Thanks man! Thanks again. Regards.... Maybe i'm going blind